# is this a bug? am i "overflow"ing the array?

Tags: c

**Really can not figure out what is the problem with this C code!**

*Am I overflowing the array?*

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
void main() {
  int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
  for (i = 0; i <= ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    array[i] = "A";
}
```

Comment: `array[i] = "A";` is a type error. Please turn on all warnings.

Comment: also your array is of size `10` and therefore the `<=` will read up to index 10, which is the 11th element, and out of bounds

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are 0 indexed. The last element is at array[9], as such, change:

```
 i <= ARRAY_SIZE
```

to

```
i < ARRAY_SIZE
```

Otherwise 'i' will become 10, and you will have

```
array[10] = "A";
```

Which is out of bounds.

Additionally, "A" is a char pointer, but you're assigning it to an int.

Comment: "A" is a `char[2]`

Comment: For the purpose of assignment, `"A"` decays to a pointer to char.